# R program : Performing a left_join on two datasets (struggling to find an appropriate key)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, data-cleaning, data-wrangling

I am trying to perform a left_join on my two datasets called "regional_clean_long" and "river_data". However, I am not able to find an appropriate key to join these two datasets.

My current code is this:

```
joined_df <- left_join(regional_clean_long, river_data, by = "regions_nz")
```

But I believe that my key is incorrect and I am not sure how to join these datasets accordingly. this is the  [regional_clean_long data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zkyYA.png) which is essentially landcover area
and this is my [river_data data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcsYn.png). Any help would be appreciated as my output looks like this [output imgae](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxNWp.png). My end goal would be to have each region consisting of MCI & Taxarichness values and the associated land area over time

I have tried to omit the "by." parameter however it returns the following [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/84I2r.png)

Comment: Seems like you need to join in `regions_nz`, `cover_type`, and `year`, no?

Comment: If you omit the `by=` parameter, then the left join would do this automatically.

Answer (score 0):

`regional_clean_long` has four columns and `river_data` has five. They have three in common (`regions_nz`, `cover_type` and `year`).

If you just join "by" one of these three common columns it will duplicate the other two.

So you have to join by all three which you can do in one of two ways.

1. `left_join(regional_clean_long, rivers)`
2. `left_join(regional_clean_long, rivers, by=c("regions_nz", "cover_type", "year")`

With 1, R will figure out which columns to join by automatically. With 2, you obviously specify them yourself.

If you are new to this and will continue this in the future it is overwhelmingly likely that you will use `left_join` all the time so it's worth reading up on.

Good luck!